# Rails multi-column IN clause

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a `User` model with `first_name` and `last_name` attributes and I want to find all `Users` that have one of the names in a given array. For example, if my array is ["John Doe", "Mary Jane", "Little John"], I would want to do the following `mysql` query

```
SELECT (*) FROM `users` WHERE ((first_name, last_name) IN (('John', 'Doe'), ('Mary, Jane'), ('Little', 'John')))
```

Is there a rails friendly way to write this query?

Answer (score 3):

Your array is something like that:

```
my_array = ["John Doe", "Mary Jane", "Little John"]
my_array.collect{|m| m.split(" ")}
```

Above code build 2D array. After the above code *my_array* vaue is:

```
[["John", "Doe"], ["Mary", "Jane"], ["Little", "John"]]
```

Now replace square brackets with parenthesis:

```
resultable_key = my_array.inspect.gsub("[","(").gsub("]", ")")
```

Query building is complete. Now make the query in db:

```
User.where("(first_name, last_name) IN #{resultable_key}")
```

This is exactly equilent to your query:

```
SELECT (*) FROM `users` WHERE ((first_name, last_name) IN (('John', 'Doe'), ('Mary, Jane'), ('Little', 'John')))
```